# Найти массивы, которые дают при операции "ислючающее или" между собой - ноль

Tags: python, python-3.x

Найти массивы, которые дают при операции "ислючающее или" между собой -  ноль. Чтобы их найти нужно сделать полный перебор всех возможных случаев, но у меня не получается перебрать все эти случаи, помогите.

а - двумерный массив:

```
[
    [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
    [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
]
```

результат равен 0, если нет операндов, равных 1, либо их чётное количество.

В данном примере такими массивами будут:

```
а0⊕а2⊕а5⊕а7 = 0
а0⊕а3⊕а5 = 0
а2⊕а3⊕а7 = 0.
```

```
а0⊕а2⊕а5⊕а7 = 0
a0⊕а3⊕а5 = 0
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код программы:

```
#a = [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]   
a = [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
    flag = True
    mass = []
    mass_k = []
    mass_p = []
    sum_2 = 0
    
    for i in range(len(a)): #цикл по каждому массиву
        for k in range(i, len(a)): # цикл исключающий i-тый массив
            for l in range(1, len(a)): # цикл, отвечающий за количество суммируемых массивов
                m = k
                if k == i:
                    pass
                else:
                    for j in range(len(a[0])): # цикл, который пробегает по вложенному массиву
                        mass_k = []
                        try:
                            for p in range(l):
                                sum_2 += a[k][j]
                                mass_k.append(k)
                                k += 1
                        except IndexError:
                            pass
                        sum = a[i][j] + sum_2
                        sum_2 = 0
                        k = m
                        if sum % 2 != 0:
                            flag = False
                            break
                        flag = True
                    if flag:
                        mass_p = []
                        mass_p.append(i)
                        for m in range(len(mass_k)):
                            mass_p.append(mass_k[m])
                        if l == len(mass_p)-1:
                            mass.append(mass_p)
                    flag = True
    
    print(mass)
```

Comment: а вопрос то какой?

Comment: @Zhihar Мой алгоритм рассматривает не все возможные варианты

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr = [
  [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
]


def arr_xor(arr1, arr2):
  return [obj[0] ^ obj[1] for obj in zip(arr1, arr2)]


def analyze(arr, index, res, path):

  for i in range(index, len(arr)):

    current_path = path + [i]

    if len(res) == 0:
      new_res = arr[i]
    else:
      new_res = arr_xor(res, arr[i])

      if any(new_res) is False:
        print(current_path)

    analyze(arr, i + 1, new_res, current_path)


analyze(arr, 0, [], [])
```

Comment: Очень красиво, спасибо большое))